# ParseFilePipe validator for FileType validator returns error even with correct file

Tags: nestjs, backend, dto

Im sending with postman with form-data two files, it doesnt matter which type of file im sending it always return error

code:

```
@Public()
@Post()
@ApiOperation({ summary: 'Create driver' })
@UseInterceptors(FileFieldsInterceptor([
{ name: 'cedula', maxCount: 1 },
{ name: 'proceedings', maxCount: 1 },
],

))
create(
@Body() createDriverDto: CreateDriverDto,
@UploadedFiles(new ParseFilePipe({ validators:  [new FileTypeValidator({fileType: 'jpg'})]}))
files: { cedula?: Express.Multer.File[], proceedings?: Express.Multer.File[] }) {
console.log(files.cedula);

return this.driverService.create(createDriverDto, files);
}
```

[postman error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SfIiB.png)

Comment: [here's](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/blob/6363cbe29d131f54361adf6e0a3367253345b255/packages/common/pipes/file/file-type.validator.ts#L23) the source of the method that will run against your file. Looks like the `file.mimeType` doesn't match with `'jpg'`

Comment: I believe the mime type is `image/jpeg`, try `'jpeg'` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem adding helper to validate files, here is the code:

Controller:

```js
@Patch('/uploadfiles/:id')
@ApiOperation({
  summary: 'Upload driver files'
})
@UseInterceptors(FileFieldsInterceptor([{
    name: 'dniFront',
    maxCount: 1
  },
  {
    name: 'dniBack',
    maxCount: 1
  },
  {
    name: 'driverLicenseFront',
    maxCount: 1
  },
  {
    name: 'driverLicenseBack',
    maxCount: 1
  },
  {
    name: 'proceedings',
    maxCount: 1
  },
  {
    name: 'selfie',
    maxCount: 1
  }
], {
  fileFilter: fileFilter,
}))
uploadFiles(
  @Param('id', ParseUUIDPipe) id: string,
  @UploadedFiles() files: {
    proceedings: Express.Multer.File[],
    dniFront: Express.Multer.File[],
    dniBack: Express.Multer.File[],
    driverLicenseFront: Express.Multer.File[],
    driverLicenseBack: Express.Multer.File[],
    selfie: Express.Multer.File[]
  }) {
  return this.driverService.uploadFiles(id, files)
}
```

Helper:

```js
import {
  HttpException,
  HttpStatus
} from '@nestjs/common';


export const fileFilter = (req: Express.Request, file: Express.Multer.File,
  callback: Function) => {
  const fileExtension = file.mimetype.split('/')[1];
  const validFiles = ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'pdf']
  if (validFiles.some(el => fileExtension.includes(el))) return callback(null, true)
  return callback(new HttpException(`${file.fieldname} is not a valid document`, HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY), false)
}
```